# Is it possible to trigger an event when an element of my scroll view reach a certain position?

Tags: android, scrollview, listener, horizontalscrollview

I'm using an HorizontalScroll view with android.

I would like to know if technically, it is possible to trigger an event (like changing the text of a textview ) when a specific element of my scrollview reach a certain position (for example when an element become the first visible element starting from the left of the scrollview).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```
Rect scrollViewBounds = new Rect();
scrollView.getHitRect(scrollViewBounds);

if (yourElementView.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollViewBounds)) {
    // your element (or portion of it) is in visible area
    // you can trigger your event
} else {
    // your element is not in visible area
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rami! That's a good start however I still have two problem: It must be kind of a listener since the scroll can change at every instant, and I need to know when my element is on the left part of the scroll view ( however I can still get by with your answer :)  ). Do you know if those things exist? If not I'll keep that solution

Comment: **1)** You can add a `scrollListener` to your HorizontalScrollView and use his methods. **2)** You can use `yourElement.getLocationOnScreen(int[] location);` and check if `x = location[0] < 0` (if X<0 that means your element is in the left half of th screen.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it as soon as possible.